# subprocess output when using stdout.pipe shows escape characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in python programming and trying something.
I have my code which checks for a substring in stdout 
   and    return if it finds the specific string but 
if it doesnt find the string, 
  process continue running and works as expected

but further output comes with escape characters (no color output).

```
import subprocess
import time
import sys
import os
import re
import glob

def invoke():
    run = subprocess.Popen(['pwd'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    for line in run.stdout:
        sys.stdout.write(line.decode('utf-8'))
        print('\033[31m' + 'Hello' + '\033[0m')  # Red text

    run.wait()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    invoke()
```

Comment: How is `red` involved? What is `run_command`? Why the extra indentation after the `Popen` line (did you omit relevant code)? We need a [MCVE] to help.

Comment: thanks for looking into it, i have updated and written a smaller function.

Comment: I just ran your exact code (post-edit) in bash on Ubuntu on Windows, using `python3` (3.8.0 specifically), and it outputs the current directory (in my normal text color), followed by `Hello` in red as expected. What is your OS? Terminal program? Shell? Are you expecting some other behavior?

Comment: I am using 3.3.4 . i observed that when i run from cmd it shows me these escape character not color but if i run from mingw64 , it shows me hello in red color.

Comment: You're displaying the output of a docker session in the Windows command line? As in `cmd.exe`? To my knowledge, it doesn't directly support inline ANSI colors codes like that (at least, not without programs that interact in [native UTF-16 mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#example); Python uses a ASCII superset locale). Attempting to run `py -3 -c "print('\x1b[31mHello\x1b[0m')"` in my `cmd.exe` produces garbage for the escapes, it doesn't change colors.

Comment: for me cmd.exe returns for demo code:
←[31mHello←[0m
for my docker output i saw if dont mention anything for stdout in subprocess.popen , it gives me color output of make from docker as is, but if i add stdout=subprocess.PIPE in popen(), it gives me ascii codes for color

Comment: At a guess, when directly connected to the terminal, `docker` is smart enough to perform the Windows-specific work to convert the color codes. But when sending to a pipe, either it doesn't perform the conversion or Python's default encoding mechanism doesn't support outputting it as you expect. I don't know which of these possibilities is correct though.

Comment: Hmm, make sense but i am not sure though .is there a way in python where we can switch back from pipe to direct after i found the string.

Comment: It's technically possible [on some systems via `ptrace`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4059/152396), but it would be a pain to pull it off from Python (assuming Windows allows similar shenanigans at all). More importantly, it likely wouldn't go any good; `docker` is likely checking [`isatty`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isatty) only once, when launched, and determining the behavior to use based on that initial check, so even if you reattached it to the terminal, it would still be *acting* on the belief that it wasn't attached to a terminal.